# Had Anakin Skywalker killed anyone before Dooku?

Tags: star-wars, anakin-skywalker

Was Count Dooku his first kill or had he already slain many a foe?

Comment: This question should probably be more specific. Canon only or Legends? Kill by personal combat only (i.e. lightsaber) or are starfighter kills acceptable? Force-sensitive foes or any foe? As it is, all of your answers so far are very different yet all correct.

Comment: im unsure of all the downvotes, while being a very Simple question, its not a bad question.

Comment: @Himarm - downvote arrow's hover-over explicitly states "**Does not show any research effort**". There's a difference between "simple" and "a basic fact which is a major plot point in a movie that is easily accessible; and covered on Wikipedia in detail". I'm rarely one to dump on questions, but this one deserves all its downvotes and frankly, none of the upvotes it got thanks to bikeshedding...

Comment: @Himarm ... curiously enough, from comments on the answer, the OP seems to have intended to ask a much more interesting and less basic question; and I have a strong feeling THAT one would have gotten none of the downvotes but also far less upvotes :)

Comment: @dvk I knew about the sand people, I had changed the question to discount them, someone changed it back. I did google it I didn't get anything interesting.

Comment: @Josh - that's because - and it's a good policy - the questions aren't allowed to be changed if they invalidate existing valid answer. The downsides of violating that policy far outweigh its risks.

Comment: @dvk link to that policy?

Comment: @cde - I doubt I'll have time to search today, so you're more likely to get a timely response asking on Meta

Comment: @cde : Basically, the version of the question you see above ("Was Dooku his first kill?") was what I responded to (first) with my answer below.  The OP indicated that he intended to ask a different (more specific) question.  He altered it but I rolled it back, according to the policy that DVK refers to, which is designed to protect answerers from drastic changes in questions.  I tried to be fair and suggested that the OP ask a new question --- the one that he intended.  (Note, if I had allowed the OP to change his question in the way he wanted to, then Himarm's answer would *also* be invalid.)

Comment: @praxis I understand the history of the post, it's the question can't be changed policy i wanted to read

Comment: @cde : No worries.  Here's a meta article on the issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48345/what-is-the-etiquette-for-changing-the-substance-of-a-question

Comment: @Praxis my answer is still safe even with his edits. he had said excluding tuskan raiders, and sand people, the deaths in this droid ship would have been Neimoidian most likely, which are defenitly considered as "people" http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Neimoidian

Comment: @Himarm : Fair enough. If you look through some of the comments from the OP though, he also seems to be rejecting anything that isn't canon in the strictest sense, and so N_Soong's answer may have become obsolete if further edits to the question were made....the point is, minor adjustments and clarifications are fine, but drastic changes to questions after answers have already been provided are not. (Also, who knows if Neimoidians are "people" by OP's standards.  One way to intepret the comments is that people = humans for OP.)

Comment: @Himarm OP has stated in the comments that he was looking for first "close up kill" within canon (see comments to N_Soong's answer), so OP would disqualify your answer if allowed to edit his question as he pleased. Of course, this is why I asked for clarification in the very first comment to the question...

Comment: Anakin certainly sucked the life out of the prequel movies...that counts.

Comment: @Himarm - What is the purpose of this bounty? What are you wanting to see?

Comment: @Himarm Are you wanting to get the attention of the OP so they can finally clarify what they were asking?

Comment: wut would you like to know

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Yes

As a canon example of Anakin killing a human by lightsaber prior to his execution of Dooku, Anakin killed [Tal Merrik](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tal_Merrik).

[image: Tal Merrik impaled on a lightsaber]

This image is from *The Clone Wars* S02E13 ["Voyage of Temptation"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Voyage_of_Temptation).

Comment: Is clone wars canon anymore?

Comment: @Himarm The [TV series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(TV_series)) that this answer is from, yes.

Comment: I love how Obi-Wan then says "Anakin..." not mad,  just kind of disappointed that he just un-necessarily killed somebody.

Answer (score 108):

## Many Tusken raiders died to bring you this information.

Enraged by his mother's death, Anakin had slain an entire camp of Tusken raiders, including women, children...possibly even their animals.

This went down in *[Attack of the Clones](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_Attack_of_the_Clones)*, prior to his fight with Dooku.

[image: Tusken raider beggar]

Comment: Ok I meant to exclude them because in another question I asked they weren't really considered "people". Sorry I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker : Fair enough, but I suggest you ask it again as a new question...otherwise my answer gets invalidated.

Comment: sorry I just saw it or I would have just asked a new question

Comment: You can just roll back the edit, and ask the new question.  I will roll it back...if you disapprove, just say so.  :-)

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker If Sand People aren't people, why is the word "people" in their name?  They aren't even weird misshapen aliens.  They have two arms, two legs, two eyes, and a mouth.  They carry rifles.  They wear goggles.  They seem like people to me.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker At least in SW:KOTOR the Sand People are clearly shown as sentient beings, with their own culture. See also [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sand_People).

Comment: "I Slaughtered them, like Animals. " Also he killed a shit load of people in the first movie. when he blew the spaceship up...

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker I'm not butthurt.  They're fictional characters.  I wasn't being serious. However, seeming like animals to their neighbors doesn't make much difference.  You could say the same thing about Native Americans and Europeans.

Comment: The killing of the sandpeople is definitely a significant moment in Anakins character development. When he confesses it, the significance is emphasized by a very obvious musical cue: It's the first time a few notes from The Imperial March are played - the theme music of Darth Vader from the original triology.

Comment: He "killed them all. And not just the men, but the women and the children too."

Comment: @Axelrod In  a previous question I was told he faced no repercussions for killing them because no one cared because they were considered  animals. That and he didn't really tell anyone.

Comment: Had the Jedi council known about the slaughter, they would have punished him severely.

Comment: @cde but not as much as they would punish him if he killed real people.

Comment: Considering the sand people are natives to the planet, and the humans are unwanted colonists, that makes the sand people native American counterparts. Any human instance if demonizing the sand people is just racism.

Comment: @cde lol that's ridiculous

Comment: surely you mean speciesism.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker I can't find this other question you mention that proves sand people aren't people. The answers to your sand people related questions all seem to talk about how he kept it quiet, not about how they we're not considered murder victims.

Answer (score 107):

One time Anakin blew up a droid control ship with people on it in orbit around Naboo.  This happened in *Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace*, during the Battle of Naboo. This was while he was nine, so his earliest kills on record in my opinion.

[image: Droid command ship exploding]

This ship contained at least 10 non-droids as per [this](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lucrehulk-class_Droid_Control_Ship) tech guide for Episode One.

Comment: It's also likely that he killed people while pod racing (whether or not those deaths were intentional or accidental is unknown).

Comment: @zzzzBov That depends on your definition of people. I believe he is said to be the only human participating in pod races.

Comment: @kasperd people would be all of the species in the race. As they are all intelligent or "sentient" as classified in starwars.

Answer (score 64):

#### Yes he had

(Note: this is a compilation of all answers found thus far plus some more research on my part - consider upvoting the other answers for this question as well)

Here's a list:

- A gorgoodon (a non-sentient creature, but I thought I'd mention it): [Jedi Quest: Path to Truth](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Quest:_Path_to_Truth)
- [Krayn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Krayn) the slave trader (when he was 13) (Source: [Anakin on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker)) (note: NOT canon)
- The persons on the ship he destroyed in *The Phantom Menace* (kudos to Himarm)
- The Tusken Raiders following the death of his mother in Episode II (kudos to Praxis - although I did know that one myself!)
- Tal Merrik in the series *The Clone Wars* (kudos to Null)
- Genosian Warriors in *The Clone Wars* (kudos to Nu'Daq)
- Saato in [*Star Wars: The New Droid Army*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_New_Droid_Army) (a video game, I know, but just thought I'd add that one in too)
- Trenox (again *Star Wars: The New Droid Army*)
- [Messo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Messo) (Legends)
- Denturi (Anakin's Wookieepedia page cites that he had killed this person, but I can't find much more about Denturi other than that)
- [Durge](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Durge) (was killed by being 'force-pushed' into a star - what a way to die!) (kudos to Matemáticos Chibchas)

Comment: You got me this time...I was keeping these up my sleeve in case the question was re-posted (with more specific language). ;-)

Comment: @Praxis sorry i'm just now getting back to check on things, it seems a lot has happened since yesterday. I was looking for first up close kill, I admit I also had forgotten about the ship Anakin blew up when he was a child. Is Krayn the slave trader Disney cannon?

Comment: No, it's a comic in Legends

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker : Like cde said, its extended universe material.

Comment: Please include [Durge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Durge) in the kill-list.

Comment: Meh. Not cannon and the ones that are cannon are already up there. Thanks tho.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker no worries ;)  Just wanted to give more of a list answer

Comment: Good thorough answer +1. Anny was really a violent guy wasn't he?

Answer (score 17):

Also, in the foundry scene in *Attack of the Clones*, he sliced up some Geonosian warriors.

Comment: Well spotted --- I forgot that.